# backshift operator notation

Tags: notation, time-series

- Original equation:

$$\begin{equation}
     z_t = \phi z_{t-1} + z_{t-1} - \phi z_{t-2} + \omega_t
\end{equation}$$

- Rewrite the equation, re-arrange terms, and factorize them:

$$\begin{align}
   z_t - z_{t-1} &= \phi (z_{t-1} - z_{t-2}) + \omega_t \\
   (z_t - z_{t-1}) - \phi (z_{t-1} - z_{t-2}) &= \omega_t \\
   (1 - \phi B)(z_t - z_{t-1}) &=  \omega_t \\
   (1 - \phi B) \bigtriangledown z_t &=  \omega_t \\
   (1 - \phi B)(1 - B)z_t  &= \omega_t
\end{align}$$

**BACKGROUND:**

I'm trying to understand backshift operator notation in the context of this ARIMA example from machine learning time series https://github.com/etcrago/Tutorial-Arima-w-jeffrey-yau (lecture 2).

**QUESTION:**

In the 3rd line he somehow jumps to $(1-B)$, but my understanding is the $\phi$ 
 part of the equation should be factored to $(B-B^2)$, not $(1-B)$.  How does the author jump to that $(1-B)$ factorization ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: DONE.   Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I misread this problem.  The better way to look at it is that the author factored $(z_t−z_{t−1})$ out such that the equations do work when multiplied to $(1-\phi B)$.